Why does the error CME: 256 occur during AT^SISO=0 in TCP communication, even when all settings are perfectly configured?
Problem Description
Hello, I am currently testing communication between a computer and a cellular modem before using the cellular modem with an MCU.
The modem I am using is a 3G-only modem, and it follows the Hayes 3GPP TS 27.007 and 27.005 AT command standards. I have inserted an LTE/5G SIM card from my smartphone into the modem. While I have configured all TCP communication settings perfectly, I encounter a +CME ERROR: 256 when executing AT^SISO=0.
Port 5001 is in the LISTENING state.
Inbound and outbound traffic for port 5001 is allowed in the firewall rules.
The server program is running without issues.
When using AT+CGDCONT to set the carrier's 3G network APN, a CME ERROR: 133 occurs, and no IP address is assigned. However, when using the 4G network APN, the IP address is assigned successfully. As a result, I am currently using the 4G APN.
My SIM card is subscribed to a plan that supports 3G/LTE/5G networks. Could using the 4G APN on a 3G-only modem cause any issues?

Current Modem Status:
AT+CREG?
+CREG: 0,1
OK
AT+CSQ
+CSQ: 18,99 (According to the modem datasheet, a BER value of 99 appears to be its default.)
OK
AT+CGACT?
+CGACT: 1,1
OK
AT+CGATT?
+CGATT: 1
OK
AT+CGDCONT?
+CGDCONT: 1,"IP","lte.sktelecom.com","10.125.173.26",0,0
OK
AT^SISS?
^SISS: 0,"srvType","Socket"
^SISS: 0,"conId","1"
^SISS: 0,"address","socktcp://49.254.169.124:5001"
^SISS: 0,"tcpMR","10"
^SISS: 0,"tcpOT","6000"
OK
AT^SISO=0
+CME ERROR: 256

Expected Behavior
When executing AT^SISO=0, I expect my server program to terminate.

Server Program
Below is the server program that listens on port 5001 and terminates when a client (modem) connects:
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>

WSADATA wsaData;

struct addrinfo* result = NULL, *ptr = NULL, hints;
#define PORT_NUM "5001"

int main()
{
    int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0)
    {
        printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
    }

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, PORT_NUM, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0)
    {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Error at socket(): %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    iResult = bind(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Listen failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    SOCKET ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
    if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("accept failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
}


It's embarrassing, but it was a very simple issue: it happened because I didn't configure the SICS settings!
